# How to Signout GoogleApiClint from another Activity or Fragment android

Tags: android, android-fragments, google-oauth, android-googleapiclient

i am using Google Api Clint for login with google account. my code is working fine, but when i am trying to sign out from a fragment `Logout.java`, its not working please see my login Activity code below.

in oncreate

```
GoogleSignInOptions gso = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
                .requestEmail()
                .build();

        mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                .enableAutoManage(this, this)
                .addApi(Auth.GOOGLE_SIGN_IN_API, gso)
                .build();

        // Customizing G+ button
        btnSignIn.setSize(SignInButton.SIZE_STANDARD);
        btnSignIn.setScopes(gso.getScopeArray());
```

And rest of the Code

```
@Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

          if (requestCode == RC_SIGN_IN) {
            GoogleSignInResult result = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInResultFromIntent(data);
            handleSignInResult(result);
        }
    }


private void signIn() {
        Intent signInIntent = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInIntent(mGoogleApiClient);
        startActivityForResult(signInIntent, RC_SIGN_IN);
    }


    private void signOut() {
        Auth.GoogleSignInApi.signOut(mGoogleApiClient).setResultCallback(
                new ResultCallback<Status>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResult(Status status) {
                        updateUI(false);
                    }
                });
    }

    private void revokeAccess() {
        Auth.GoogleSignInApi.revokeAccess(mGoogleApiClient).setResultCallback(
                new ResultCallback<Status>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResult(Status status) {
                        updateUI(false);
                    }
                });
    }

    private void handleSignInResult(GoogleSignInResult result) {
        Log.d(TAG, "handleSignInResult:" + result.isSuccess());
        if (result.isSuccess()) {
            // Signed in successfully, show authenticated UI.
            GoogleSignInAccount acct = result.getSignInAccount();

            Log.e(TAG, "display name: " + acct.getDisplayName());

            String personName;
            //String personPhotoUrl = acct.getPhotoUrl().toString();
            String email;
            String gid;
            String location = "Location Not Set";
            String oarth = "Google";
            String gender = "Not Set";

            if(acct.getDisplayName() != null){
                personName = acct.getDisplayName();
            }else{
                personName ="";
            }
            if(acct.getEmail() != null){
                email = acct.getEmail();
            }else{
                email ="";
            }
            if(acct.getId() != null){
                gid = String.valueOf(acct.getId());
            }else{
                gid ="";
            }

            Log.e(TAG, "Name: " + personName + ", email: " + email
                    + ", id: " + gid +", location:" +location+", oarth: "+oarth+", gender: "+gender);

            //session.setMember(gid, personName, location, gender, email, oarth);
            InsertFbLogindata(gid, personName, location, gender, email, oarth);

            updateUI(true);
        } else {
            // Signed out, show unauthenticated UI.
            updateUI(false);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        int id = v.getId();

        switch (id) {
            case R.id.btn_sign_in:
                signIn();
                break;

            case R.id.btn_sign_out:
                signOut();
                break;

            case R.id.btn_revoke_access:
                revokeAccess();
                break;
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();

        OptionalPendingResult<GoogleSignInResult> opr = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.silentSignIn(mGoogleApiClient);
        if (opr.isDone()) {
            // If the user's cached credentials are valid, the OptionalPendingResult will be "done"
            // and the GoogleSignInResult will be available instantly.
            Log.d(TAG, "Got cached sign-in");
            GoogleSignInResult result = opr.get();
            handleSignInResult(result);
        } else {
            // If the user has not previously signed in on this device or the sign-in has expired,
            // this asynchronous branch will attempt to sign in the user silently.  Cross-device
            // single sign-on will occur in this branch.
            showDialog();
            opr.setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<GoogleSignInResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onResult(GoogleSignInResult googleSignInResult) {
                    hideDialog();
                    handleSignInResult(googleSignInResult);
                }
            });
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(@NonNull ConnectionResult connectionResult) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onConnectionFailed:" + connectionResult);
    }

    private void updateUI(boolean isSignedIn) {
        if (isSignedIn) {
            btnSignIn.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            btnSignOut.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            btnRevokeAccess.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        } else {
            btnSignIn.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            btnSignOut.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            btnRevokeAccess.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
    }
```

in my logout Fragment

```
public class logout extends Fragment {

    Button Logout;

    Session session;
    LoginActivity la;

    private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater,ViewGroup container,Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.sent_layout,container,false);
        final Button logout = (Button)root.findViewById(R.id.buttonLogout);
        logout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
             public void onClick(View view) {
                session = new Session(getActivity());
                Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), LoginActivity.class);
                       intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
                       intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                       intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                  session.setLogin(false);
                  LoginManager.getInstance().logOut();

                 Auth.GoogleSignInApi.signOut(mGoogleApiClient);

                 Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Logged Out", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                startActivity(intent);
             }

        });
        return root;
    }
```

}

i tried so many examples but no use. is there any possible to this. please suggest the best way.

Answer (score 0):

your activity code is absolutely fine but in login.java, you have to change some code as follows.

1. get instance of googlesigninoptions
2. firebase authentication
3. that's it you can call `mAuth.signout()

```js
    GoogleSignInOptions gso = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
            .requestIdToken(getString(R.string.server_client_id))
            .requestEmail()
            .build();
    mGoogleSignInClient=GoogleSignIn.getClient(

    getActivity(),gso);
    mAuth=FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        mGoogleSignInClient.signOut().

    addOnCompleteListener(getActivity(),
        new OnCompleteListener<Void>()

    {
        @Override
        public void onComplete (@NonNull Task < Void > task) {
        SharedPreferences getUser = getActivity().getSharedPreferences("user_info", getActivity().MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor ed = getUser.edit();
        ed.putString("username", null);
        ed.commit();
        Snackbar.make(v.getRootView().findViewById(R.id.settings_fragment_layout), "Logged Out Successfully", Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        HomeFragment hf = new HomeFragment();
        getFragmentManager()
                .beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.fragment_container, hf)
                .commit();
    }
    });
```